# V-for creating different instances of vue agile slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm trying to make a slide for my website with vue-agile but whenever I use:

`<img class="slide" v-for="ad in ad_place_1" :key="ad.id" :src="ad.image_url"/>`

It creates different instances of `agile__slides agile__slides--cloned` instead of just loading the `img` tag with the `class="slide"` for each item in the data.

I followed the example: https://codepen.io/lukaszflorczak/pen/xezgmO

My code:

```css
.agile {
  max-width: 1270px;
}

.agile__slides,
.agile__track,
.slide,
.agile__list {
  width: 100%;
}

.agile__actions {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.agile__actions button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.agile__actions button {
  color: #888
}

.agile__actions .agile__dot button {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.agile__actions .agile__dot button:hover,
.agile__actions .agile__dot--current {
  background-color: #888
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-agile"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-agile/dist/VueAgile.css">
<agile ref="carousel" :dots="true" :infinite="true">
  <img class="slide" v-for="ad in ad_place_1" :key="ad.id" :src="ad.image_url" />
  <template slot="prevButton"><span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span></template>
  <template slot="nextButton"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></template>
</agile>
```

The HTML in the website:

```html
<div class="agile__track" style="transform: translate(0px); transition: transform 0ms ease 0s;">
  <div class="agile__slides agile__slides--cloned"><img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/ruby-files/images/ruby.png" class="slide"><img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/ruby-files/images/colvin-pt.jpg" class="slide"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ruby-files/images/theproteinworks38.jpg"
      class="slide"></div>
  <div class="agile__slides agile__slides--regular"><img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/ruby-files/images/ruby.png" class="slide"><img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/ruby-files/images/colvin-pt.jpg" class="slide"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ruby-files/images/theproteinworks38.jpg"
      class="slide"></div>
  <div class="agile__slides agile__slides--cloned"><img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/ruby-files/images/ruby.png" class="slide"><img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/ruby-files/images/colvin-pt.jpg" class="slide"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ruby-files/images/theproteinworks38.jpg"
      class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

I have 3 items in my data and as you can see its creating 3 instances of the `agile__slides--cloned` instead of creating the 3 corresponding `img` items with `class="slide"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
   <div  v-for="ad in ad_place_1" :key="ad.id">
    <img class="slide" :src="ad.image_url"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did that but there is some problem when I do that, that makes the image not take full width or be mixed with other slides that wy I kinda need the only img tag version

Comment: you can apply css on img tag so it will take complete width of the parent.

Comment: I believe I did that. The problem is that when I do it the way I showed its creates 3 slides with 3 image tags inside when i should create 1 slide with 3 images inside

Comment: Managed to fix it by adding slides-to-show criteria so it only shows 1 slide at the time

Comment: Hi @DeadSec, slides-to-show is not working for me. How did you do it?